# I don't get pings from person A between unignoring person A and refreshing the page in Chat

Tags: bug, chat, ping, ignored-users

When chatting, after I unignore somebody, but before I refresh the page, when that person mentions me or replies to me, I don't get the ping sound nor the green bubble indicating the amount of mentions/replies.